# why buildSuggestion method of SearchDelegate is not working?

Tags: flutter, dart

**When I type something in the textfield, no suggestion matching with the character typed in TextField is being returned by the buildSuggestion method of SearchDelegate. Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code**

The below code is my TextField widget.

```
TextField(
            onTap: (){
              showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());
            },
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: 'tahoma', // font-style for input text.
            color: ColorPalette.secondaryColor),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 3),
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
        ),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: ColorPalette.primaryColor,
        suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.my_location,
            color: ColorPalette.secondaryColor,
        ),
        hintText: 'Search Parking Area',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: ColorPalette.secondaryColor,
              wordSpacing: 5,
              fontSize: 18),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Constants.rad),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorPalette.primaryColor),
        ),
                  ),
                )
```

The below code is my custom searchbox which is a SearchDelegate.

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final cities = ['Ankara', 'İzmir', 'İstanbul', 'Samsun', 'Sakarya'];
  var recentCities = ['Ankara'];

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          })
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(child: Text(query)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? recentCities
        : cities.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context);
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: suggestionList[index].substring(0, query.length),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: suggestionList[index].substring(query.length),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you `print(suggestionList)` do you see correct items?

Comment: No. Empty list is getting displayed @pskink